# How is cpu's state saved by os without altering it?

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu, context-switch

During the context switch the operating system (OS) needs information from the CPU to create a Process Control Block (PCB), but accessing the CPU could alter the very information it's trying to capture. please tell me how this is handled.

I have read books on operating system but none of them go into it as i recall. I am unable to find any answer on the web too.

Comment: Depending on the ISA, the CPU already saved the user-space stack pointer somewhere as part of handling an exception and transferring control to kernel code.  e.g. on x86-64, an interrupt handler runs with the stack pointer already pointing at this process's kernel stack, where the kernel can just `push` all the registers to create that user-space context which it can restore later.  The `int 0x80` legacy 32-bit system-call entry point into a 64-bit kernel is similar to that: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64_compat.S#L267

Comment: On MIPS, two of the 32 registers are reserved for async use by interrupt handlers, for the CPU to put values in which exception / interrupt handlers read.  (When MIPS was new, 32 registers was a *lot*.  Newer ISAs with 32 registers don't waste them, they have separate special registers.)

Comment: On x86-64, `swapgs` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/swapgs) and a segment-override to use a non-zero GS segment base is the intended way for the kernel to get a "pointer" to some per-task space it can store stuff in (at least temporarily).  The kernel only has to allocate "PCB" storage when creating a task, it just has to find it again when switching away from it.  ("PCB" is a generic label for a concept; different OSes have different actual internal data structures and don't usually actually store user-space register state next to stuff like PIDs and open file-descriptors.)

Comment: SO the TLDR is: The hardware saves the state that could be altered, and the context switch code uses that.

Comment: This is tricky because saving the state alters the state. The best explanation of this I read was in the book "Operating System the XINU approach", by Douglas Comer. While it is somehow obsolete, informations there are all you need to understand how this could be made efffectively.